# Return relational value in function

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have the following function prototype:

```
void bubble (int work[], const int size, int (*compare)(int a, int b));
```

As you can see it needs as third parameter, a function pointer. Later in main, I give these parameters: `bubble(a, SIZE, ascending)` where "ascending" is a function with the following definition:

```
int ascending(int a, int b){return b < a;}
```

The program runs without an error or warning (in devCpp) and my question is how is this possible? How can I return a relational operator with two integers in an `int` function? And what is the real returning value?

Comment: The return value is an `int`, what else did you expect it to be?

Comment: The result of that operation is 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison has the answers (or any good C book)